# How to close a complicated path in canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to draw an oval in canvas. Basically, I combine four bezier curves to an oval.

I successfully draw an oval but I don't know how to close it.

Codes:

```
//Paints for bazier curve
Paint bezierPaint = new Paint();
bezierPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
bezierPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
bezierPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
bezierPaint.setStrokeWidth(3.0f);
bezierPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

//Oval Path
Path ovalPath = new Path();

//Draw the first curve. from top point to right point
ovalPath.moveTo(160,0);
ovalPath.cubicTo(210, 0, 260, 100, 260, 150);

//Draw the second curve. from right point to bottom point   
ovalPath.moveTo(260, 150);
ovalPath.cubicTo(260, 200, 210, 300, 160, 300);

//Draw the thrid curve. from bottom point to left point         
ovalPath.moveTo(160, 300);
ovalPath.cubicTo(110, 300, 60, 200, 60, 150);

//Draw the fourth curve. from left point to top point           
ovalPath.moveTo(60, 150);
ovalPath.cubicTo(60, 100, 110, 0, 160, 0);

**//I expect this oval close correctly. But in actually, the fourth curve was closed. 
//Please see the image in attachment.How should I close this path as my expectation?**
ovalPath.close()

canvas.drawPath(ovalPath, bezierPaint);
```

[image]

Comment: why didnt you use Shape (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/OvalShape.html) and resize(x,y) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html#resize(float, float))

Answer (score 3):

Just drop the call to `path.close()`. This function adds a line segment from the current draw point to the first draw point. I don't think there's any harm to skipping this call.

Alternatively, pay more attention to the orientation of your segments so that each one starts where the last ended, and more importantly, so that the last one ends where the first one started.

Or do what marnaish said, and use `drawOval()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is quite easier to use following function to draw an oval:

```
canvas.drawOval(ovalRect, paint);
```

The ovalRect is a [RectF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html) Object in which the oval will find its place.